# VirtualBox проброс портов для django

Tags: python, django, virtualbox

Есть CentOS 7 на виртуалке уставленный с python3.6 и Django

Пытаюсь пробросить порты через правила проброса:
Хост(127.0.0.1:2555) Гость(10.0.2.15:22) - это для ssh робит норм
Хост(127.0.0.1:2666) Гость(10.0.2.15:8000) - это для Django не робит запускаю так
 runserver 10.0.2.15:8000

Хочу чтобы можно было просматривать сайт из браузера хоста. Тип подключения NAT

Comment: может быть, есть смысл решить вопрос кардинально и, избавившись от Virtual Box'а, запускать python и Django в Docker'e?

Comment: может вы и правы, но только с одной стороны) Мне же ещё виртуалка с centOS нужна.